# Selenium Ant Error - com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.transformValues

Tags: ant, selenium-webdriver

I am running a Test Using Ant and i am getting the error as below:

Its a Simple test to Open a Website. Even though the browser is Opening , the website is not. Same works fine if i run the code from eclipse itself. The jars are all downloaded from Maven Repo.

```
com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.transformValues(Lcom/google/common/collect/ListMultimap;Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ListMultimap;

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.transformValues(Lcom/google/common/collect/ListMultimap;Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Lcom/google/common/colllect/ListMultimap;
    at com.google.common.net.MediaType.toString(MediaType.java:708)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpCommandCodec.encode(JsonHtttpCommandCodec.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnnection.execute(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:170)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.exeecute(FirefoxDriver.java:393)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:568)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java::242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FiirefoxDriver.java:221)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriiver.java:212)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriiver.java:125)
    at com.tests.AppTest.testLogin(AppTest.java:17)
```

Here is my POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.tests</groupId>
  <artifactId>MavenProject</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>MavenProject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.47.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>18.0</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have tried adding gauva jar in Eclipse, but it does not help. I am not sure what is missing in here. Please help.

Comment: Do you have an older version of guava somewhere in the classpath (or some other duplicate jar files)?

Comment: This is the first time i have nstalled gauva jars, instead installed my maven.. Never used gauva before..  What shd i be looking in classpath to look for duplicates??

Comment: I mean to check if you have more than one version of any jar files in the classpath.

Comment: No, checked that.. No duplicates

Comment: @MasterJoe2 they have removed that question.